# Solving inner product equation

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\Vert x \Vert =\Vert y \Vert.$
I want to **find all** $z \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$$\langle x,z \rangle = \langle y,z \rangle.$$
For simplicity, we may use dot product
$$\langle x,y\rangle = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3 y_3$$

It is obvious when $z = x \times y$ so that $z \perp x$ and $z \perp y.$ Hence, $\langle x,z \rangle = 0 = \langle y,z\rangle.$

But I think there are another $z.$
For example:
$$ x = (2,3,0)$$
$$ y = (1, \sqrt{12}, 0)$$
Clearly $\Vert x \Vert = \Vert y \Vert.$
We can choose $z = (0,0,1)$ or in general $z = (0,0, k) k \in \mathbb{R}, k \not = 0$, and hence $\langle x,z\rangle = 0=\langle y,z \rangle.$

But I can find  $z = (\sqrt{12}-3, 1, 1)$ or in general
$$z = (b(\sqrt{12}-3), b, 1), b \not = 0, b \in \mathbb{R} $$
so that
$$ \left (\begin{matrix}
   2\\
   3\\
   0
   \end{matrix} \right )  \left (\begin{matrix}
   \sqrt{12}-3 \\
   1\\
   1
   \end{matrix} \right )=
   \left (\begin{matrix}
   1 \\
   \sqrt{12} \\
   0
   \end{matrix} \right )  \left (\begin{matrix}
   \sqrt{12}-3 \\
   1\\
   1
   \end{matrix} \right )$$

Or in general
$$ \left (\begin{matrix}
   2\\
   3\\
   0
   \end{matrix} \right )  \left (\begin{matrix}
   b(\sqrt{12}-3) \\
   b\\
   1
   \end{matrix} \right )=
   \left (\begin{matrix}
   1 \\
   \sqrt{12} \\
   0
   \end{matrix} \right )  \left (\begin{matrix}
   b(\sqrt{12}-3) \\
   b\\
   1
   \end{matrix} \right ), b \not =0, b \in \mathbb{R}^3.$$
In my opinion, vector $z$ will depend on $x,y$ and so its formula.
In summary:

Given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\Vert x \Vert =\Vert y \Vert.$
I want to **find all** $z \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$$\langle x,z \rangle = \langle y,z \rangle.$$

For early observation, we may use dot product.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\langle x,z \rangle = \langle y,z \rangle$$ is same as $$\langle x-y,z \rangle =0.$$ This means $z$ is orthognal to $x-y$. If $x=y$ then every $z \in \mathbb R^{3}$ satisfies this. Otherwise, the set of all vectors orthogonal to $x-y$ is the plane through the origin with $x-y$ as normal vector.

So the answer is $\{(a,b,c): an_1+bn_2+cn_3=0\}$ where $(n_1,n_2,n_3)=x-y$.

Comment: If you use the cosine form of the dot product, you'll find that $||x|| = ||y||$ implies that $z$ must lie in the plane that reflects $x$ and $y$ onto each other.